# Printing vector layer with labels not in cp1252 encoding via GeoServer MapFish printing module?

Tags: mapfish, mapfish-print

I'm printing vector layer via GeoServer Printing Module (MapFish Print 2) of GeoServer 2.15. MapFish only supports fonts COURIER, HELVETICA, TIMES_ROMAN in cp1252 encoding for labels. It's very limiting restriction because cp1252 have very little symbols, but let not discuss such a decision. Instead, I want a solution for using symbols outside that charset in features labels, in particulaly cyrillic. I hasn't even idea how to do that.